# RemoteApp Prevent User from Running Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop, remoteapp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow only RemoteApp, not Remote Desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/154127/allow-only-remoteapp-not-remote-desktop)

We've setup an application to run remotely under RemoteApp on Windows Server 2008.  To do so we had to open up the standard RDP port.  Unfortunately that also means that someone with the appropriate knowledge and credentials can now also access the server's desktop remotely.  Is there anyway to allow access to a RemoteApp without also allowing access to the desktop.

Answer (score -1):

You can restrict remote desktop to a specific group, and limit them to a specific application.

Read the below link to configure the subject things in easy step by step.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730673(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: That's a somewhat vague answer. Can you include the steps necessary?

Comment: To limit who can connect via remote desktop use the "Remote Desktop Users" group. To specify what remote users will run use Terminal Services Configuration, right click on the connection for properties and use the Environment tab.