# Deny Remote Desktop by TS Gateway (and keep RemoteApp)

Tags: remote-desktop, gateway

Through a TS Gateway Server 2012 remoteapp are availables, by this way, we can also access to the remote desktop of the server which provides the remoteapp, by using mstsc and specify the gateway, I don't want it.

So how can I deny logging through mstsc by the gateway (only direct connection 3389) but keep access by 443 for the remote app, or deny the remote desktop by the ts gateway ?
(obviously, the remote desktop is not part of the collection of the remote app, but it still works)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The RemoteApp is transparently using the gateway server to launch the application and it is using the RDP protocol.

Duplicate question: [Allow only RemoteApp, not Remote Desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/154127/allow-only-remoteapp-not-remote-desktop)

Comment: it's not exactly what, I want to keep remote desktop classic access (mstsc + 3389). Want I want to forbidden is Remote desktop access through ts gateway + 443, but keep access to the published remoteapp.

Comment: This is not possible. Like I said before, the RemoteApp uses exactly what you want to disable to provide the application to clients.

Comment: Ok, but I think strange enable only application publication, force enabling remote desktop throught this ts gateway.

Comment: Your last comment is confusing and fragmented. Can you edit it or provide clarification?

Comment: You seem to say that enable RemoteApp by a TS Gateway on a server, force to enable also Remote Desktop on this server, I think it's strange.

Comment: That is correct and not strange at all. It is the underlying protocol it utilizes.