# How do I setup a RemoteApp?

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access, remoteapp

I have a server within my network that has a program that users needs to access.  I don't want to allow them to access anything else but this program.  From looking at these questions:

### [Allow only RemoteApp, not Remote Desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/154127/allow-only-remoteapp-not-remote-desktop)

and

### [RemoteApp Prevent User from Running Remote Desktop](https://serverfault.com/questions/111770/remoteapp-prevent-user-from-running-remote-desktop)

It appears what I am trying to accomplish is a RemoteApp.  How do I setup a single program as a RemoteApp?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a couple of ways.  Create a custom msi file for the app or create a custom rdp connection.  Check out the RemoteApp Manager which is installed as part of the Remote Desktop services.

I'm not sure why this was downvoted unless perhaps its for not having enough information or perhaps not including a step-by-step.  So, here's the [step-by-step](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730673%28WS.10%29.aspx) from Microsoft. : )